# How to rebuild kernel for wacom tablet driver?

Tags: drivers, kernel, 16.04, tablet, wacom

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 and my Wacom CTL-471 *completely* crashes the system every time I get near the surface with the pen. Every time I have to reboot, nothing helps.

So I found out that these lines 2429 - 2437 are actually a patch.
[Linus Torvald's github repo](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hid/wacom_wac.c#L2429)

I couldn't find info when will Ubuntu officially get 4.5 kernel so I decided to do it on my own. I would like to somehow build (if possible) only this file and patch my kernel asap.

Newb question: If I patch it this way, and a few weeks later there is official Ubuntu update to linux 4.5.2 will it be installed by default update manager?

Any educational info on this is also welcome in the comments.

Thanks

Comment: input-wacom, the Wacom Linux driver now contains the updates: https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/files/xf86-input-wacom/input-wacom/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If time is of the essence you can try building the branch of the Wacom driver which contains those updates which have not yet made it into a release:

```
git clone http://git.code.sf.net/p/linuxwacom/input-wacom 
cd input-wacom 
git checkout -b 4.6jiri remotes/origin/jiri/for-4.6
./autogen.sh
make 
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r wacom
sudo modprobe wacom
```

More information on the driver can be found here:

http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Input-wacom

Comment: It works. Thanks! Will it be overwritten when new kernel gets released via update?